# How to make current time automatically update in AVAudioplayer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer, playback

I want to know that : How to make currentTime automatically update in AVAudioplayer.
I use this code

```
    let currentTime1 = Int((player1?.currentTime)!)
    let minutes = currentTime1/60
    let seconds = currentTime1 - minutes * 60
    curLabel.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
func startRecording() -> Void {
        ....
        .... 
     let aSelector : Selector = #selector(CLASSNAME.updateTime)
     timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector,userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

}


func updateTime() {
        let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime
        let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
        elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)
        let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
        elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)
        let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
        let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
        YOUR-LABEL.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds)"

    }
```

now when you call the startRecording() function it will start updating the text on YOUR-LABEL

Hope it is clear now

Comment: 1. what is " START-TIME " that is in second line in func .

Comment: the reference time which you want to use as a start time

Comment: Ok, I make it 0.0
now it says that             Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Get the time like this NSDate.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: -60). . . you can put any number of seconds instead of 60

Comment: here startTime is global variable  " private var startTime = NSTimeInterval() "